# What's wrong with this line according to W3C validator?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Line 14, Column 64: Bad value checkbox for attribute type on element input. - W3C validator

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
```

How do I fix this? Must be something incredible simple but I can't figure it out.

Exact error: http://puu.sh/eMNs5/e5ec16bab1.png

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: What kind of error did it show? Also it probably needs `name="show-menu"` or `value=""`

Comment: Can you post the full HTML page you're trying to validate?

Comment: Rather not post the whole HTML on the internet but isnt that irrelevant its only this line.

Comment: Your screen shot (http://puu.sh/eMNs5/e5ec16bab1.png) looks to me like it requires a `value="foobar"` attribute to be valid.

Comment: It's the `role="button"` that's causing it.

Comment: @wawa tried it did not solve it unfortunately.

Comment: @j08691 Removing that fixed it apparently but I don't know if it has any impact on the functionality...

Comment: Unless you're using it for something like a CSS selector or JavaScript the only other real purpose is ARIA accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" value="button" />
```

Comment: You don't have to close a tag like that in html5 or traditional html4.

Comment: what does the role attribute mean in your checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking at this, I encountered the same issue.

There are 2 parts to the problem.

1. Dependant on document type, you need to close the tag as suggested by GabrielSNM....   />  not >
2. The validator doesn't like you applying role="" to a checkbox.  so, remove role="button" to validate.  I also suggest adding name="show-menu" as this can also through an error periodically if you dont.

Answer (score 0):

Remove role attribute and use checked attribute

```
<input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked="yes">
```